# Typing Functions With Any Input in 0.9.5

Tags: typescript

I'm moving our TypeScript project to 0.9.5 and I'm not sure what to do what about one of the breaking changes.

I have a pattern where a function can take another function as input.  I don't want to place any constraints on the parameters to that input function but I do want to constrain the return type.  I was doing this:

```
declare function meta(input: (... args: any[]) => boolean): void;

meta(function (x: number, y: number): boolean {
    return true;
});

meta(function (a: string): boolean {
    return false;
});
```

but that doesn't work any more.  The best replacement I've come up with is this:

```
declare function meta(input: (x: any, y: any, z: any) => boolean): void;

meta(function (x: number, y: number): boolean {
    return true;
});

meta(function (a: string): boolean {
    return false;
});
```

That's pretty ugly and it only works up to as many parameters as I feel like including on `input`.  It just feels wrong.  Is there a better way to type my function?

Answer (score 2):

The suggested change on the [breaking changes page](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Known%20breaking%20changes%20between%200.8%20and%200.9&referringTitle=Documentation) is the following...

```
declare function meta(input: (...args: any[]) => boolean): void;

meta(function (x?: number, y?: number): boolean {
    return true;
});

meta(function (a?: string): boolean {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That does compile but it has its own problems.  If not all of the parameters are actually optional the signature is misleading.  That makes the code less maintainable.