# Typescript 0.9.5 does not allow for variable number of arguments in callbacks?

Tags: typescript

I cannot figure out how to resolve the error caused by the second call to greeter.invoke.  I believe this is due to 0.9.5 changes.  Am I mistaken in thinking the declaration is saying the callback may contain any number of parameters?  It seems to have the exact opposite affect and require the callback to accept 0 parameters.

```
class Greeter {
    invoke(context: Object, fn: (...args: any[]) => void, args: any) {
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var greeter = new Greeter();
    greeter.invoke({}, () => { }, {});
    greeter.invoke({}, (a) => { }, {});
};
```

The error is this:

Error   1   Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
    Call signatures of types '(a: any) => void' and '(...args: any[]) => void' are incompatible:
        Call signature expects 0 or fewer parameters.   J:\Code\VS2013\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\app.ts 9   13  TypeScriptHTMLApp1

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201150/typing-functions-with-any-input-in-0-9-5 which states all parameters should be optional.

Comment: Rest arguments are now properly checked for function arity

Description: You will need to properly handle functions with rest args as if they could have 0 or 1 arguments in the position of the rest arg. For example:

function myFunction(f: (...args: string[]) => void) { }

myFunction((x, y) => { }); //0.9.1.1
myFunction((x?, y?) => { }); //0.9.5

Reason: The compiler was unintentionally too lenient in this case and allowed errors where functions were mismatched. We have tightened it to prevent these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since variable number of arguments implies all arguments are optional, functions you use should define arguments as optional as well, notice `greeter.invoke({}, (a?) => { }, {});`:

```
class Greeter {
    invoke(context: Object, fn: (...args: any[]) => void, args: any) {
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var greeter = new Greeter();
    greeter.invoke({}, () => { }, {});
    greeter.invoke({}, (a?) => { }, {});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For your callback function declaration, use `Function` instead:

```
class Greeter {
    invoke(context: Object, fn: Function, args: any) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I suggested to the author of my d.ts file.  Specifically for dojo.require.  Thanks for this.